# Migrating to 2.6 and Form error No implementation for play.i18n.Messages was bound

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

In my project I define a `SignupForm` outside the scope of a Controller ... the reason being I need reusing it from different source files.

```
package views.form

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.Messages

case class Signup(email: String, password: String, repeatPassword: String, name: String) extends MyUsernamePassword

@Singleton
class SignupForm @Inject() (implicit val messages: Messages) {
  val Instance = Form {
    mapping(
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "repeatPassword" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Signup.apply)(Signup.unapply).
      verifying(messages("playauthenticate.password.signup.error.passwords_not_same"),
        data => (data.password != null) && data.password.equals(data.repeatPassword))
  }
}
```

But this leads to the runtime error `No implementation for play.i18n.Messages was bound`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrate to `MessagesApi`:

```
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.i18n.{Lang, Langs, MessagesApi}

case class Signup(email: String, password: String, repeatPassword: String, name: String) extends MyUsernamePassword

@Singleton
class SignupForm @Inject() (implicit val langs: Langs, val messagesApi: MessagesApi) {
  implicit val lang: Lang = langs.availables.head
  val Instance = Form {
    mapping(
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "repeatPassword" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 5),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Signup.apply)(Signup.unapply).
    verifying(messagesApi("playauthenticate.password.signup.error.passwords_not_same")(lang),
      data => (data.password != null) && data.password.equals(data.repeatPassword))
  }
}
```

You'll need to specify your languages in your configuration file. For example, `play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-US", "fr" ]`. More details can be found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaI18N).

Comment: thanks!! I had been using the `MessagesApi` before but it required a Lang implicit which after migrating to 2.6 is no longer injected. I read here to use Messages instead: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaI18N#Using-Messages-and-MessagesProvider.

Comment: One Q: why is it picking up any arbitrary lang in the statement `val lang: Lang = ...`? I'd expect it to come implicitly from a request somewhere ... however, it does the job, the runtime error is gone now.

Comment: @SkyWalker I just copied in `val lang: Lang = langs.availables.head` as dummy code, but I believe you would normally pull the language from the request like `val lang: Lang = request.messages.lang`, but in your case since this is outside your controller you'll need some logic to pick the right language, request-independent (not sure how you're doing that now)